# How to keep track of objects in an Array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I need help in keeping track of objects in an array. I have tried giving each object an arrayIndex var, so I can splice by getting that var which represents the index in the Array.

```
object0.arrayIndex = 0;
object1.arrayIndex = 1;
object2.arrayIndex = 2;
object3.arrayIndex = 3;
```

But this is problematic if you move objects to different arrays. Objects would move from different places and therefore the arrayIndex var needs to be constantly updated.

I have done this by adding an static ID to each object. With a for loop I check each object for the corresponding object ID I want to splice

```
var objectID:Number = objectArrayTarget.id;
for (var t:int; t<_objectArrayLayer1.length; t++)
{
    if (objectID == _objectArrayLayer1[i].id)
    {
        var indexOfObject:Number = (_objectArrayLayer1.indexOf(_objectArrayLayer1[i]));
    }
}
_objectArrayLayer1.splice(indexOfObject, 1);
```

While this works is there a more efficient way of keeping track of objects in an Array? With 100+ objects this might create some slowdown

P.S. These objects are getting spliced and then pushed to a new array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your  "Objects would move from different places" means same object from one place to another place, there is no arrayIndex  needed

```
var indexOfObject:Number = _objectArrayLayer1.indexOf(targetObj);

if (indexOfObject >= 0) {

    _objectArrayLayer1.splice(indexOfObject, 1);
}
```

If it means different object, like a copy, you could compare some properties to get the targetObj

```
for (var t:int = 0; t<_objectArrayLayer1.length; t++)
{
     if (targetObj.id == _objectArrayLayer1[i].id)//assume id is unique key of the object
     {
          break;//i is the index here

     }
}

if (i != _objectArrayLayer1.length) {//find target object

}
```

If the object type has a unique key, like a id, or you can make a unique key with some properties of the object, like name + "_" + order, you could use dictionary, Like  Patel mentioned.

```
var dic:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);

dic[obj1.id] = obj1;
dic[obj2.id] = obj2;//assume id the unique key,or you can use other key
```

So you can find obj like this

```
var obj:Object = dic[target.id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an Array.
I think you should use a Set implementation like Hashset
You'll get constant-time lookup, no sorting required,you can add,remove and lookup for object.